# Using ajax to grab information from database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I m using codeigniter and would like to grab some user info with ajax. This is what I have but it s not working

In the view I have a defined variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var end_user = "<? echo $user_id; ?>";
</script>
<div id="tabs6"></div>
```

js file:

```
function get_experience()
{
$.post(base_url + "index.php/home/get_experience", { user : end_user }, function(data) {
           if (data.status == 'ok')
           {
$("div#tabs6").html(data);
           }
        else
           { //nothing }
           }, "json");
}

            get_experience();
```

controller:

```
public function get_experience()
    {
            $this->load->model('experience_model');
            $end_user = $this->input->post('user');

            $one_exp = $this->experience_model->one_exp($end_user);

            if ($one_exp->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                    $one_exp_html = '<ul>';
                    foreach($one_exp->result() as $exp)
                    {
                            $one_exp_html .= '<li>';
                            $one_exp_html .= $exp->experience;
                            $one_exp_html .= '</li>';
                    }
                    $one_exp_html .= '</ul>';
                    $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $one_exp_html);
                    return json_encode($result);
                    exit();
            }
            else
            {
                    $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => 'nothing here');
                    return json_encode($result);
                    exit();
            }

    }
```

model:

```
function one_exp($end_user)
    {
            $query_str = "SELECT experience FROM exp WHERE user_id = ?";
            $query = $this->db->query($query_str, $end_user);
    }
```

Comment: why you using html in a controller and not passing `$one_exp` to a view?

Comment: _Its not working_ - have an error message?

Comment: no error messages. and I tried passing the `$one_exp` like this `$data['one_exp'] = $this->experience_model->one_exp($end_user);
                $this->load->view('one_view', $data);` but it's returning Message: Undefined variable: one_exp

Comment: What happens when you just `print_r($this->experience_model->one_exp($end_user));`?

Comment: did this `$data['print'] = print_r($this->experience_model->one_exp($end_user));
$this->load->view('one_view', $data);` Message: Undefined variable: print
Filename: views/one_view.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `return $query` to your `one_exp` method.

**EDIT**

You're setting `user_id` in your view, but then using `end_user` in your javascript function `get_experience()`.

Also, since it's `json` you'll need to change the html fill to

```
$("div#tabs6").html(data.content);
```

For more debugging add an alert to your callback (right before `if (data.status == 'ok')` add `alert(data);`)

Comment: tried ... still nothing. `$query_str = "SELECT experience FROM exp WHERE user_id = ?"; $query = $this->db->query($query_str, $end_user); return $query;`

Comment: I added the alert and it's alerting null. In my view I have `var end_user = "<? echo $user_id; ?>";` So all that is ok.

Comment: Do more debugging. Verify `$end_user` is what you're expecting in your `get_experience()` method in your controller.

Comment: I got it working. It was a combination of two answers. I needed to echo the result. What Crinsane suggested and add content here `html(data.content);`

Answer (score 1):

You've got to echo the result out I think, not return it.

Comment: `echo json_encode($result);`? tried ... and still won't display anything

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but problem occurs in end_user value in js.Try this one
View File:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var end_user = "<? echo $user_id; ?>";
    get_experience(end_user);
</script>
<div id="tabs6"></div>
```

The js file:

```
    function get_experience(foo)
    {
        $.post(base_url + "index.php/home/get_experience", { user : foo }, function(data) {
           if (data.status == 'ok')
           {
$("div#tabs6").html(data);
           }
        else
           { //nothing }
           }, "json");
}
```